# Unity launcher autohide leaves "ghost" behind?

Tags: unity, graphics, launcher, 12.10, autohide

In 12.04 I had the launcher set to autohide, which worked perfectly.

However in 12.10 I am getting a strange "ghost" issue.

Take this screenshot, with me having a maximised google chrome window, mousing over the back button.
[image]

As well as this, I also get another ghosting issue when I have the panel set with an opacity, whereby whatever is in approximately the middle left of the screen gets mirrored up to to panel, but only when I move/switch to a window.

But that one is not so annoying as the autohide bug, how can I fix that?

Comment: It should be graphics issue. Are you using unity 2D? Do you have any external graphics card?

Comment: I believe is a bug too. I asked a question here:

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/213598

Your input might be useful there.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me too. Since I have an nvidia card I enabled `proprietary drivers` and now it works.

To do this, open the `Software Sources` via the Dash (or through System Settings) and hit the `Additional Drivers` tab.

If autohide doesn't work that means it simply doesn't work. I have to press Meta key to see it.

Answer (score -1):

just get back to 12.04 as it more stable and fast . if you want 12.10 wait for few mouth until they fix issues.Save your time and nerves.Its jupiterbroadcasting studio advice very interesting http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/25971/ubuntu-12-10-review-las-s24e01/